# How can I print values in array whose key is an odd number using javascript function

Tags: javascript

Here is how I did it but it prints prints out a random quote from an object that contains quotes as values and number indexes as keys.

```
displayRandomQuote = function () {
    var quotes = {
        0: "All computers wait at the same speed.",
        1: "A good programmer looks both ways before crossing a one-way street.",
        2: "Computers do not solve problems, they execute solutions.",
        3: "The best thing about a boolean is even if you are wrong, you are only off by a bit",
        4: "Ubuntu is an ancient African word, meaning 'can’t configure Debian'",
        5: "Without requirements or design, programming is the art of adding bugs to an empty 'text' file."

    }
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(quotes).length);

    console.log(quotes[rand ]);
}
displayRandomQuote();
```

Comment: What have you tried to filter only the odd keys? Please post it

Comment: Instead of generating a number from 0 to n, try generating a number from 0 to n/2 and then double it and sum 1, making sure to cover every odd number! Beware of the cases where n is even and odd.

Comment: Why aren't you using a regular array?

Answer (score 0):

```js
displayRandomQuote = function () {
    var quotes = {
        0: "All computers wait at the same speed.",
        1: "A good programmer looks both ways before crossing a one-way street.",
        2: "Computers do not solve problems, they execute solutions.",
        3: "The best thing about a boolean is even if you are wrong, you are only off by a bit",
        4: "Ubuntu is an ancient African word, meaning 'can’t configure Debian'",
        5: "Without requirements or design, programming is the art of adding bugs to an empty 'text' file."

    }
    var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (Object.keys(quotes).length / 2)) * 2) + 1;

    console.log(rand + ': ' + quotes[rand]);
}

displayRandomQuote();

//
// OR:
// (You should use a regular array)
//

BETTERdisplayRandomQuote = function () {
    var quotes = [
        "All computers wait at the same speed.",
        "A good programmer looks both ways before crossing a one-way street.",
        "Computers do not solve problems, they execute solutions.",
        "The best thing about a boolean is even if you are wrong, you are only off by a bit",
        "Ubuntu is an ancient African word, meaning 'can’t configure Debian'",
        "Without requirements or design, programming is the art of adding bugs to an empty 'text' file."

    ]
    var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length / 2)) * 2) + 1;

    console.log(rand + ': ' + quotes[rand]);
}

BETTERdisplayRandomQuote();
```